# Is there a way to send a TCP packet as another application?

Tags: security, sockets, networking, tcp, penetration-testing

I have one **Windows 7** machine with one ***.exe** application (**app-target**) using **TCP** to connect to some server.

I need to know if there is a way I could write an app (**app-tester**) in any language, that will run on the same machine at the same time as **app-target**, that send packets to that server, masquerading as **app-target**.

I'm aware of some **TCP** attacks (**man in the middle** for example), but I'm not quite sure about the implementation of this particular attack. I need to know **how to implement it**.

Any info / link will be welcome. A web search ends up with many different concepts.

**Update**

I have read about [TCP Sequence Prediction Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Sequence_Prediction_Attack), and seems to be a starting point. But that attack relies on leaving the application **unresponsive**. I want the application to be **running** as well, so I believe the way to go would be using a **Proxy**.

So now the question, more specific, is how do you **force** an app to be a **proxy** of another, in terms of **networking**?

Comment: The question does seem to be coherent. What do you mean by "masquerading as app-target"? There's nothing in a TCP packet that identifies the application that caused the OS to send it.

Comment: In a networking point of view it's pretty clear that I should just send packets to the active connection. But I'm asking about the actual implementation on how you should do it in programming. All examples I found out are for establishing a connection, not using a connection of another application.

Comment: How you should do *what*? What do you mean by "using a connection of another application"?

Comment: "using a connection of another application" means that the app-target application has already connected and made the necessary checks to establish the connection. I need to use that connection in order to send packets to the server, thinking that my app-tester application is app-target.

Comment: You mau use a proxy or a firewall to divert the traffic to a proxy-like application :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this. TCP doesn't know know which application incoming packets are from. It only knows what host and port they come from. From the TCP point of view, all you need to do is open a connection.

However the *application* may have an authentication/authorisation protocol, such as a username/password exchange, a client SSL certificate, etc. You'll have to research the actual application you're communicating with to determine that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I want to reuse the existing connection, not create a new one, as the server limits the connections to one per IP.

Comment: You should have said so in your question. You can't do that.

Comment: Why I can't do that? I'm pretty sure it is possible, doing a Proxy or prediction attack. I'm don't know about the actual implementation, which was the original and current question.

Comment: @Veehmot It's really hard to understand precisely what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to steal a connection from another application, use it, and then give it back to it? That can be done on most platforms, but it's very ugly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes, exactly. Like a forced proxy. Ugliness or elegance was never questioned, as I'm trying to make a tool to test again possible attacks. Anything goes. If you have any link or info related to that, it would be awesome to have it.